# Ace high flush being beaten by full house

Tags: texas-hold-em

In Texas holdem, with 8 players what are the odds of having an Ace high flush being beaten by a full house?

I ask, because I've seen this a few times (in an online game)  - and inevitably the person with the Ace high flush goes all in, and is then shocked at the (losing) outcome...

Comment: Only happens if the board is paired.  Any flush is beat so not sure why you focus on ace high.  Question is not clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

A flush should not be that surprised on a paired board.  A player is not likely to put it all in without quads, boat or a big flush. There are a lot more quads plus boats than big flush.  With a flush on the board they are not as likely to bluff.

On a paired board your opponent has a boat or quads with any of 4 pair.  If the opponent is not paired there are 2X9 = 18 hole cards that would make a boat.

There are just over 1 million paired boards so versus a random hand only like 0.002800%.  But you cannot go with that as you are not facing a random hand here.

Hero:
A♠J♠

Villain:
9♥8♥

Board:
T♠9♠9⋄5♠8♣

If the villain calls the flop and turn and jams the river then hero needs to think twice about a call.  Hero should not be surprised when villain shows a boat.

Answer (score 0):

any full house beats all flushes in normal HE. I have heard of short deck HE where in some rooms a flush does beat a full house.

Comment: Interesting but does not answer the stated question.